Segmenting CISCO SF300-48 Manageable Switch for four devices with four identical IPs
I am a complete IT noob so please forgive me if this is a dumb question. I am an automation engineer at a manufacturing plant. Long story short, we received four production computers that all have identical IPs and sub nets and for some reason we are not allowed to/cannot change them. My coworker found an old SF300-48 Cisco switch lying around and he asked me to play around with it (learning experience type thing) and see if I can make it so that I can get these four computers connected to this one switch without an IP Duplicate error. Playing around with the switch, I have set the switch so that it is a layer 3 device and have created four VLANs, with the one port assigned to each VLAN (The ports were all set to access mode). However, this is the point I am stuck at. With the same IP and subnets on all computers, I can only get one of the computers to successfully ping the switch, that being the one whose third octet matches the octet of its VLAN (e.g. Device with IP XXX.XXX.10.1 is able to ping VLAN with IP Interface XXX.XXX.10.254 but other Device with IP XXX.XXX.10.1 who is connected to port on separate VLAN is unable to ping that VLAN's IP interface XXX.XXX.20.254). With that in mind, I ask, is there any way to configure such a set up, where these four devices stay with the same IPs but are able to communicate to the switch without crossing. I don't even know if my method of testing is correct. Thanks.

Duplicate networks requires NAT, and you cannot NAT on the switch, it requires a router.

In any case, you should get the device manufacturer to replace the duplicate addressed devices. You should also be able to configure any device you own that is attached to your network.

@RonMaupin Welcome to the world of industrial crap. Sometimes (alright, always) there's things you don't get to change.


we received four production computers that all have identical IPs and sub nets and [..] we are not allowed to/cannot change them

A seriously flawed design of the 'braindead' category. I would recommend challenging that design decision because it has permanent consequences for your network.
If you stick with the flawed design, isolating the computers from each other using VLANs is the first step. You could also connect the computers to a router directly, leaving out the switch VLANs. However, routing isn't possible like that, the point where you're stuck at.
Routing requires unambiguous IP addresses and subnets. To get there, you need translation - destination NAT. With a single NAT router, that router requires support for separate routing domains (VRF) to handle ambiguous addressing. Short of that, each computer requires a separate NAT router. An L2/L3 switch won't do as it can't translate.
Using NAT, each router (instance) is assigned an unambiguous address on your normal network. It then translates/port forwards specific transport-layer ports to the assigned computer behind it, e.g.

TCP 192.0.2.1:80 -> XXX.XXX.10.1:80 on Computer 1's VLAN/router port
TCP 192.0.2.2:80 -> XXX.XXX.10.1:80 on Computer 2's VLAN/router port
TCP 192.0.2.3:80 -> XXX.XXX.10.1:80 on Computer 3's VLAN/router port

